# How to select elements from this array

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays. If arrayTwo has color "blue and "red" then return  "blue painting", "red sofa", "blue pot" from arrayOne.

```
var arrayOne = ["green wall", "blue painting", "red sofa", "yellow shelf", "blue pot"];

var arrayTwo = ["blue", "red"];

for (var i=0; i < arrayOne.length; i++ ) {
if (arrayOne[i] == "blue" || "red"){
// this should give colors that match in arrayOne 
 }
}
```

edit: I want to know if the words match in array one and two. But not hardcoding it.

Comment: Maybe explain your problem and what you are trying to do. Are we talking about prefixes of the elements in arrayOne?

Comment: Is the desired output an array of elements in arrayOne that have prefixes found in arrayTwo?

Comment: The words can be in any order" Blue painting" or "true blue"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use regular expressions for that:

```
var arrayOne = ["green wall", "blue painting", "red sofa", "yellow shelf", "blue pot"];

var arrayTwo = ["blue", "red"];
var regex = new RegExp('^(' + arrayTwo.join('|') + ')');
for (var i=0; i < arrayOne.length; i++ ) {
    if (arrayOne[i].match(regex)) {
       // this should give colors that match in arrayOne 
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I don't want to hardcode  `.match(/^(blue|red)/)`.

Comment: Not just prefix. Word can be matched like "blue wall" or "true blue"

Comment: @Ann just remove `^` from regex.

Answer (score 0):

As a basic algorithm, you could loop over each element in the first array , split it using the String.prototype.split method and compare the first word with the elements in second array. if it matches, you can print the element at that index.